# RPM installation succeeds but rpm -q fails

Tags: rpm, sles

I'm trying install some packages on a SLES12.2 VM.
The command I use is

`rpm -ivh --nodeps package_rpm_name`

It looks like the rpm is installed since
`rpm -qa | grep package_name`

returns the package name but when I try to check it using
`rpm -q package_name`
it returns that the package is not installed.

Besides that uninstalling the package doesn't work since it says the package is not installed and installing it again doesn't work since it says the package is already installed.

I've found some similar issues that were suggested to use `rpm --rebuilddb` but i've also read that it is not a good practice and the problem will eventually return if we use it.

I don't if it is related to the issue but this happened after I edited the file `/etc/fstab` and removed the `sync`.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your `/etc/fstab`. We need your exact wording, because it sounds like the `rpm -q` you are putting more information than needed. Just put the name. `rpm -qa` gives you name, version, arch, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Added “echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches” before installing the rpms and it solved the issue.